# Open CV face detection using viola opencv_core2410d.dll is missing

Tags: c++, opencv, dll, face-detection, viola-jones

i am using Open CV for face detection using viola 
and i followed all the instructions here 
http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/introduction/windows_visual_studio_Opencv/windows_visual_studio_Opencv.html#windows-visual-studio-how-to
but it cannot run because of this error [opencv_core2410d.dll is missing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MEn54.png)

and it is found in \opencv\build\x64\vc12\lib

Comment: Copy `opencv_core2410d.dll` in the same folder as the .exe, Or add the libs folder to system PATH.

Answer (score 0):

Use `cmake` to get your configurations correct. Also, if you are using Visual Studio 2010, it may create a problem for 64- bit configuration. Use the later versions instead. See [this](https://karanjthakkar.wordpress.com/2012/11/21/usin-opencv-2-4-2-with-visual-studio-2012-on-windows-7-64-bit/) link if you are not using `cmake`. It is less confusing than the one you followed. Good luck!